# Iterate through Jmeter JSON response

Tags: json, jmeter

I am using **Jmeter** and getting the below response

```
[
 {
"paxJourneyID": 9431,
"name": "KIRK JAMES MR",
"gender": "M",
"flight": {
  "carrier": "ABC",
  "fltNum": "0219",
  "depDate": "2017-12-29T00:00:00",
  "board": "DXB",
  "off": "BAH"
},
"seqNum": 0,
"pnrNum": "5D293N",
"tktNum": "1412100000150",
"priority": {
  "code": "",
  "entitledClass": ""
},
"groupCode": "",
"poolID": 0,
"poolHeadID": 0,
"isPrimaryPax": true,
"parentID": 0,
"totBagPieces": 0,
"totBagWeight": 0,
"outbound": [],
"class": "Y",
"paxStatusID": 0,
"appStatusID": 1,
"primaryDoc": {
  "docTypeID": 1,
  "docNum": "B76576557"
}
},
{
 "paxJourneyID": 12356,
 "name": "GREER JOAN MSTR",
 "gender": "M",
 "flight": {
  "carrier": "ABC",
  "fltNum": "0329",
  "depDate": "2017-12-29T00:00:00",
  "board": "DXB",
  "off": "BAH"
},
"seqNum": 0,
"pnrNum": "4WMAIT",
"tktNum": "",
"priority": {
  "code": "",
  "entitledClass": ""
 },
 "groupCode": "",
 "poolID": 0,
 "poolHeadID": 0,
 "isPrimaryPax": false,
 "parentID": 123,
 "totBagPieces": 0,
 "totBagWeight": 0,
 "outbound": [],
 "class": "Y",
"paxStatusID": 0,
"appStatusID": 2,
"primaryDoc": {
  "docTypeID": 1,
  "docNum": "767"
 }
}
]
```

I have to select the part of response where parentid is 0 use it in next request. How to do the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and the following [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) query:

```
$..[?(@.parentID == 0)]
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSONPath Conditional]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)